# Deleting all terms from a vocabulary after timeout

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

When I tried to delete a vocabulary, Drupal timed out and I don't think any or all of the terms in the vocabulary were deleted. How can I delete them manually in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run sql queries directly against the database? What makes you think the terms are still there? The vocabulary table contains data about the vocabulary, and you could do a left outer join with term_data to see if there are any "orpaned" terms. So something like (assuming you haven't used a prefix on your drupal database):

```
SELECT * 
FROM term_data t
LEFT OUTER JOIN vocabulary v
ON t.vid = v.vid
WHERE v.vid IS NULL;
```

You can do a delete on a join if you need to but I suspect you won't find any orphans.

EDIT:

You should also probably check term_node as well that links terms to nodes. If you're going to run these deletes please back up your database first! Also as these queries are written, the term_node needs to run first.

```
-- Run this first
DELETE n
FROM term_node n
JOIN term_data t
ON n.tid = t.tid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vocabulary v
ON t.vid = v.vid
WHERE v.vid IS NULL;

-- Then run this query
DELETE t
FROM term_data t
LEFT OUTER JOIN vocabulary v
ON t.vid = v.vid
WHERE v.vid IS NULL;
```

Remember to back up your database first!

Comment: Yes I have access to the database. I got 4k results when I ran your query. How can I delete them now? Also is this the only query that deleting a vocabulary performs? Do I need to do any other cleaning up to mimic deleting a vocab through drupal?

Comment: Not sure if you see the edit @glumbo, but did the above help you?

Comment: Yes that helped. Sorry for not responding earlier